# Make OptionMenu Widget Scrollable?

Tags: python, tkinter

I've got an option menu that's about 60 items long and, needless to say, I can't see it all on the screen at once. Is there a way that I can make the `OptionMenu` widget in tkinter scrollable?

Comment: That sounds unpleasant to use. Can you break them up into categories and use a tree?

Comment: Unfortunately, no. Each item in the list is unique and not related to the last.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer is no, but you could try a ComboBox mega-widget (quick search will throw some suitable examples up there) which could be a 'good enough' alternative (in fact with it being a combined entry field and scrolled list you could make it 'smart' by including auto-search / auto-complete - 60 items in a drop down is a lot :)

Comment: Could you please share the link to this Tkinter widget?